# How to count total for groups by each student id

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by

```
GROUP        STUDENT    COUNT OF GROUP FOR EACH STUDENT
GROUP A      ST 1       1
GROUP A      ST 2       2
GROUP B      ST 2       2
GROUP A      ST 3       2
GROUP B      ST 3       2
GROUP B      ST 3       2
```

how to count the number of times a student entry is been for a group.
Ex. ST 1 has only one group A entry but ST2 & ST3 has 2 group entries regardless of the rows.

Please could anyone help for this SQL code.
Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way to fake `COUNT(DISTINCT` with window functions is to use `DENSE_RANK` and then `MAX` window functions

```sql
SELECT
  t.student,
  t.[group],
  CountGroups = MAX(rnk) OVER (PARTITION BY t.student)
FROM (
    SELECT *,
      rnk = DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY t.student ORDER BY t.[group])
    FROM t
) t;
```

Comment: **Why is it all in bold? Are you shouting!?**

Answer (score 3):

Ideally, you would want `count(distinct)` as a window function:

```
select t.*, 
       count(distinct group) over (partition by student) as cnt_group
from t;
```

But SQL Server doesn't support `distinct` in window functions.  Instead, you can use the sum of `dense_rank()` work-around:

```
select t.*,
       (-1 + 
        dense_rank() over (partition by student order by group asc) +
        dense_rank() over (partition by student order by group desc)
       ) as num_groups
from t;
```

Answer (score -1):

This is how you find all the relations

```
SELECT DISTINCT [GROUP], STUDENT
FROM yourtable
```

Now, let's aggregate it

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT [GROUP], STUDENT
    FROM yourtable
) t
GROUP BY STUDENT;
```